# How can I change middle item of path in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, path, powershell-5.0

I would like to invoke ImageMagick to compare images by SSIM. The images are in following directory structure:

```
+ root
  |
  +- FooBar
  |  |
  |  +- 2023-10
  |  |  \- *.png
  |  \- 2023-11
  |     \- *.png
  \- FooBar.cmp
     |
     +- 2023-10
     |  \- *.jpg
     \- 2023-11
        \- *.jpg
```

Images in `root\FooBar` and `root\FooBar.cmp` follow in some rules:

- `FooBar` is replaced with actual application name
- `root\FooBar` is original image
- `root\FooBar.cmp` is "compressed" image (how they done is not important in this question)
- They are named in format of `FooBar_%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.<millisecond>_<display_w>x<display_h>.<extension>`, where:

  - `%` and following character is replaced with corresponding C's `strftime` formatting element with taken date.
  - `<millisecond>` is replaced with the millisecond of taken date.
  - `<display_w>` is the width of the resolution.
  - `<display_h>` is the height of the resolution.
  - `<extension>` is either `png` or `jpg`.

I've tried:

```
Get-ChildItem .\root\FooBar -Recurse -Include "*.png" | % { $new = Join-Path -Path $_.Directory.Parent.Parent.FullName -ChildPath ($_.Directory.Parent.Name + ".cmp"); $new = Join-Path -Path $new -ChildPath $_.Directory.BaseName; $new = Join-Path -Path $new -ChildPath ($_.BaseName + ".jpg"); magick compare -metric SSIM $new $_  NUL 2>&1 | % ToString }
```

(`2>&1 | % ToString` avoids implicit `RemoteException`, please ignore)

However, it is not elegant because I would like to modify "middle" element of path.

For example, given `root\FooBar\2023-11\2023-11-01_02-03-04.567_890x1234.png`, corresponds `root\FooBar.cmp\2023-11\2023-11-01_02-03-04.567_890x1234.jpg`. Is there any way to shorten this where `$PSVersionTable` is following? Also what if I update PS to latest version?

```
PS> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                        
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                        
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.3570                                                                                                                                                               
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                                                                      
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                                                      
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.3570                                                                                                                                                              
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                                                              
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                                          
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                                                          
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Writing on phone, so shooting from the hip a little bit, but this *should* work (apart from some possible syntax errors / simple tweaks required).

```bash
# get fully qualified paths to folders
$leftRoot  = Convert-Path ".\root\FooBar"
$rightRoot = Convert-Path ".\root\FooBar.cmp"

Get-ChildItem $leftRoot -Recurse -Include *.png | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $leftFile  = $_.FullName;
        $rightFile = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension(
            $rightRoot + $leftFile.Substring($leftRoot.Length),
            "jpg"
        );
        magick compare -metric SSIM $rightFile $leftFile … etc …
    }
```

Comment: @mklement0 - cheers for the edits. As an aside, it’s personal taste but I prefer backtick line continuation with the pipe on the next line as it’s more obviously a continued line when you’re scanning the left of the page - if you leave the pipe on the end of the line you have to scroll right to see it and it can just look like wonky indents on the next line :-). There’s probably pros and cons of each approach and I’m not really *that* fussed either way, so happy to keep the edits.

Comment: It’s also why I prefer ```$null = …``` over ```… | out-null``` :-)

Comment: Thanks; fully agreed re `$null = ...`. To me, the line-ending `|` is only problematic if it is scrolled out of view; fortunately, in PowerShell (Core) you can now place the `|` at the start of the line even without an explicit line continuation.